# Do I need a Mac Device to have a 'signing key'?

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, key, signing

I am developing mobile application on PhoneGap. I do not have a 'signing key'. But in case, if i pay $99 to get a Apple Developer account, do I need to have an MacOS computer to develop phonegap application? I will testing the application on an iPad.

Comment: You mean you need PC with OSX or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am developing mobile application on PhoneGap.I do not have a
>   'signing key'.But in case if i pay $99 to get a Apple Developer
>   account.

To create IPA or to test the application on iPad, you should have an Apple Developer account.

> do i need to have an IOS computer to develop phonegap application ?

PhoneGap has two methods of doing this. The easier one is PhoneGap Build. Use "Build Native App on the Run menu to upload your project to their site. In a few minutes, you can download app-store ready apps for Apple iOS, Google Android, Palm, Symbian, BlackBerry and more.

The more complex method is the PhoneGap SDK. You will need to download the full development SDK, install and configure, then compile on your own machine. This method is free, but can be time consuming and tricky to set up.

See more details [here](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/tutorials/TT11.htm)